# Intervals not turning on/off on command

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, discord.js, intervals

I am working on a discord image command that sends a random image every 10 seconds. When I start the command, it works. It starts sending images every 10 seconds, but when I try to make it stop, it just won't.

What went wrong? How can I fix this?

`Image.js`:

```js
var Scraper = require('images-scraper');
const google = new Scraper({
  puppeteer: {
    headless: true,
  },
});

var myinterval;
module.exports = {
  name: 'image',
  description: 'Sends profile pics)',
  async execute(kaoru, message, args, Discord) {
    //prefix "?"

    const image_query = args.join(' ');
    const image_results = await google.scrape(image_query, 100);

    if (!image_query)
      return message.channel.send('**Please enter name of the image!**');

    if (image_query) {
      message.delete();
      myinterval = setInterval(function () {
        message.channel.send(
          image_results[Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1].url,
        );
      }, 10000);
    } else if (message.content === '?stopp') {
      clearInterval(myinterval);
      message.reply('pinging successfully stopped!');
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just simply check the `message.content` inside the `execute` method. It will never be `?stopp` as `execute` only called when you send the `image` command (i.e. `?image search term`).

What you can do instead is to set up a new message collector in the same channel and check if the incoming message is your `stop` command. In my example below I used [`createMessageCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=createMessageCollector). I've also added plenty of comments.

```js
const google = new Scraper({
  puppeteer: {
    headless: true,
  },
});

module.exports = {
  name: 'image',
  description: 'Sends profile pics',
  async execute(kaoru, message, args, Discord) {
    const query = args.join(' ');

    if (!query)
      return message.channel.send('**Please enter name of the image!**');

    const results = await google.scrape(query, 100);

    // also send error message if there are no results
    if (!results?.length) return message.channel.send('**No image found!**');

    // you probably want to send the first image right away
    // and not after 10 seconds
    const image = results[Math.floor(Math.random() * results.length)];
    message.channel.send(image.url);

    let intervalID = setInterval(() => {
      // you don't need to add +1 and take away 1, it's unnecessary
      // also, use results.length instead of the hardcoded 100
      // as if there are no 100 results, it will throw an error
      const image = results[Math.floor(Math.random() * results.length)];
      message.channel.send(image.url);
    }, 10000);

    // use this filter to only collect message if...
    const filter = (m) =>
      // the author is the same as the user who executed the command
      m.author.id === message.author.id &&
      // and the message content is ?stopp
      m.content.toLowerCase() === '?stopp';

    // set up a message collector
    const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({
      // use the filter above
      filter,
      // you only need to collect a single message
      max: 1,
    });

    // it fires when a message is collected
    collector.on('collect', (collected) => {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
      // message.reply won't work as message is no longer available
      message.channel.send('Pinging successfully stopped!');
    });

    message.delete();
  }
};
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help! I should probably go to learn more about Message.Collector now.